# How to use Moo Cloud Extension block media use another template in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am adding My Cloud Zoom Extension Block use In My Vs_Ajax Extension in Magento. Can You please suggest me how to use Cloud Zoom block in another template. I want to use in product list page. I can open product in popup using vs_ajax Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that ajax module layout file.

Check that product.info.media template file. Replace with your moo cloud zoom template file.

And necessary js into that ajax module head tag.